# Apache Spark SQL: how to optimize chained join for dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join

I have to make a left join between a principle data frame and several reference data frame, so a chained join computation. And I wonder how to make this action efficient and scalable.

Method 1 is easy to understand, which is also the current method, but I'm not satisfied because all the transformations have been chained and waited for the final action to trigger the computation, if I continue to add transformation and the volume of data, spark will fail at the end, so this method is not scalable.

Method 1:

```
  def pipeline(refDF1: DataFrame, refDF2: DataFrame, refDF3: DataFrame, refDF4: DataFrame, refDF5: DataFrame): DataFrame = {

  val transformations: List[DataFrame => DataFrame] = List(
    castColumnsFromStringToLong(ColumnsToCastToLong),
    castColumnsFromStringToFloat(ColumnsToCastToFloat),
    renameColumns(RenameMapping),
    filterAndDropColumns,
    joinRefDF1(refDF1),
    joinRefDF2(refDF2),
    joinRefDF3(refDF3),
    joinRefDF4(refDF4),
    joinRefDF5(refDF5),
    calculate()
  )

  transformations.reduce(_ andThen _)

  }

  pipeline(refDF1, refDF2, refDF3, refDF4, refDF5)(principleDF)
```

Method 2: I've not found a real way to achieve my idea, but I hope to trigger the computation of each join immediately.

according to my test, count() is too heavy for spark and useless for my application, but I don't know how to trigger the join computation with an efficient **action**. This kind of action is, in fact, the answer to this question.

```
  val joinedDF_1 = castColumnsFromStringToLong(principleDF, ColumnsToCastToLong)
  joinedDF_1.cache() // joinedDF is not always used multiple times, but for some data frame, it is, so I add cache() to indicate the usage
  joinedDF_1.count()  

  val joinedDF_2 = castColumnsFromStringToFloat(joinedDF_1, ColumnsToCastToFloat)
  joinedDF_2.cache()
  joinedDF_2.count()

  val joinedDF_3 = renameColumns(joinedDF_2, RenameMapping)
  joinedDF_3.cache()
  joinedDF_3.count()

  val joinedDF_4 = filterAndDropColumns(joinedDF_4)
  joinedDF_4.cache()
  joinedDF_4.count()

  ...
```

Comment: instead of cache, can you try using `persist` method by specifying the storage level as memory and disk

Comment: I'm curious to know why you need to have exactly 6 DataFrames (and not an undertermined number of DataFrames) or why would you need exactly N operations (and not an undetermined number of transformations).

Comment: @belka in fact it is undetermined number of data frame and transforme action, I only give an example to show the demand of the application.

Comment: @mingzhao.pro Ok I see. Try forcing the caching between each transformation and then + caching then unpersisting when the previously cached DataFrame is no longer needed. Try to do it first with only 2 operations and 3 DataFrames to check on a simplest example and iterate if that's not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to force the computation of a given `join` (or any transformation that is not final) in Spark, you can use a simple `show` or `count` on your `DataFrame`. This kind of terminal points will force the computation of the result because otherwise it is simply not possible to execute the action.

Only after this will your `DataFrame` be effectively stored in your cache.

Once you're finished with a given `DataFrame`, don't hesitate to unpersist. This will unpersist your data if your cluster need more room for further computation.

Comment: *count* is heavy and *show* will only compute a part of the Data Frame, there is really no other options?

Comment: I'm afraid the usage of **count** will also be a vulnerable point when the volume of data continue to grow

Comment: For me that's the only way to trigger an operation explicitly. Another option would be to `persist` instead of `cache` with a level defined as `StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK` or `DISK_ONLY` (at your convenience) if you don't have such a big cache on your cluster.

Comment: hey, I was left for two weeks on vacation, I will continue my research on this topic and keep updated. If you have any idea, I will be glad to test.

Comment: @mingzhao.pro if this solved your issue don't hesitate to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to repartitions your dataset with the columns before calling the join transformation.

Example:

```
df1=df1.repartion(col("col1"),col("col2"))
df2=df2.repartion(col("col1"),col("col2"))
joinDF = df1.join(jf2,df1.col("col1").equals(df2.col("col1")) &....)
```

Comment: why would we need that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new dataframe based on it. 
Ex:
val dfTest = session.createDataFrame(df.rdd, df.schema).cache() 
dfTest .storageLevel.useMemory  // result should be a true.